# Hi,In 6.0 Permission to make call is asking everytime

Tags: android

In 6.0 marshmallow, I want to add permission to making call. below code is working in all devices except Moto G, In Moto G permission is asking everytime when I start making call.

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            if(checkPermission(c, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)){
                // success
            }else{
                // faliure
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create intent service like below and add your code in that

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
        // Gets data from the incoming Intent
        String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
        ...
        // Do work here, based on the contents of dataString
        ...
    }
}
```